# Create an EditText with RadioButton in the right

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating an Activity which user can create a Question and where can create answers, so, from now I have this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewBinary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/constraintAnswerTypes"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_view_option_1_binary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/cb_answer1_binary_option"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/txt_input_option_1_binary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_option1_binary"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/respuesta_1"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/cb_answer2_binary_option"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/txt_input_option_2_binary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_option2_binary"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/respuesta_2"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the result is this one :

[image]

The problem that I'm having is if the answer that user types is too long he can not see it , so I'm thinking to do something like `match_parent` on the `width` so user has more space to write, but then I have this also :

[image]

And perhaps create 4 different lines for each answer is kinda ugly... 
My initial question is, how do I create the first output to be `match_parent` like if there's only 2 answers, but then the thing is when I have the four answers, how do I print those `EditText`?

### Edit

For the first option I want something like this, there 2 lines are the `TextInputLayout` with the `EditTexts` and the circle on the right is the `RadioButton`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code. It will solve your issue for both case, just need to handle visibility for alternate answers. If you face any issue then please let me know in comment section.

Use your own drawables and assets.

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewBinary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_view_option_1_binary"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/txt_input_option_1_binary"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_option1_binary"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Resposta 1"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/cb_answer1_binary_option"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_view_option_3_binary"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/txt_input_option_3_binary"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_option3_binary"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Resposta 3"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/cb_answer3_binary_option"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_view_option_2_binary"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/txt_input_option_2_binary"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_option2_binary"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Resposta 2"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/cb_answer2_binary_option"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_view_option_4_binary"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/txt_input_option_4_binary"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_option4_binary"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Resposta 4"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/cb_answer4_binary_option"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

For Vertical layout:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewBinary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_view_option_1_binary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/txt_input_option_1_binary"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_option1_binary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Resposta 1"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/cb_answer1_binary_option"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_view_option_3_binary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/txt_input_option_3_binary"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_option3_binary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Resposta 3"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/cb_answer3_binary_option"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_view_option_2_binary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/txt_input_option_2_binary"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_option2_binary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Resposta 2"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/cb_answer2_binary_option"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_view_option_4_binary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/txt_input_option_4_binary"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_option4_binary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Resposta 4"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/cb_answer4_binary_option"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please approve answer if it will work for you. Thanks!

Comment: This is for the 4 editText, but for the two EditTexts?

Comment: I can only see two EditTexts with your example bro

Comment: @StuartDTO i mentioned that you need to use your own assets and drawables. Change styles, color code and other things and also mentioned that use need to handle visibilty for 4 questions (linear_view_option_3_binary and linear_view_option_4_binary) set visibility **VISIBLE** for both view

Comment: This how it looks for 2 question: https://imgur.com/Xdzdl8P and for 4 questions: https://imgur.com/vcovoiK

Comment: Please can you provide the code that works? It should be 2 layouts : One with two answers(EditText) and other layout with four answers(EditText), if possible the four answers could you make them in vertical all? Because since it's a tablet it doesn't look so good, or perhaps you can do it both, like the photo you sent or as a list in vertical please

Comment: @StuartDTO I edited code with 4 answers in vertical form in above code, but the previous answer provided by me is working perfectly for 2 answers or for 4 answers (just need to handle visibility in your code). Please check again else you can put 4 answers in vertical form.

Comment: Is easy to just create 2 layouts one for 2 edittext and one for 4 edittext please?

Comment: @StuartDTO why do you want to create 2 layouts, when you will manage from single layout by handling visibility?

Comment: @StuartDTO answer provided is fulfilling your basic requirement then better you approve it, so no other person waste there time in this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:id="@+id/linear_view_option_1_binary">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight = 1
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
                android:id="@+id/txt_input_option_1_binary"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/et_option1_binary"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                      android:hint="@string/respuesta_1"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="16dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:id="@+id/cb_answer1_binary_option"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Basically we are setting layoutweit to be equal 1 on the edit text (or textinput in your case) and the width to 0dp. This way Edittext will consume only the available space, not the whole width

Comment: What I want is to have the editText matchParent and see the radioButton on the right of it

Comment: What does my answer show? It should show what you edited

Comment: Please can you provide the code that works? It should be 2 layouts : One with two answers(EditText) and other layout with four answers(EditText), if possible the four answers could you make them in vertical all? Because since it's a tablet it doesn't look so good, or perhaps you can do it both, like the photo you sent or as a list in vertical please

Comment: You probably misunderstood the usage of Stackoverflow. Here we give answers to specific problems, or hints, not solve the full problem. You asked for a way to have edit text showing the full line then radio button at the end. I showed you the code to do that. If you want to do more fields, then use the same code for more fields.

Comment: And obviously, if an answer helps you then accept it so others answer your future questions :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/txt_input"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_option"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_answer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: as well as u can use fix height of liner_view and give  android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center" to set radio button in center of textinputlayout

Comment: And what do you think it's a good design to create the 4 types of answer? and make them bigger?